# RealmSwift : All the realm rows are displayed twice

Tags: ios, swift, realm, entity-relationship

I am learning to develop on Swift, so sorry if my questions seem stupid :D
On my app, I need 3 objects : Car, Station & Conso
A Car Object can have many Conso
A Station Object car have many Conso
A Conso Object can be linked to only one Car and one Station

Here are the codes for Realm objects

Conso.swift

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

final class Conso : Object {

   //var id: Int
   @objc dynamic var idConso = ""
   //... Some fields

   @objc dynamic var data: NSData?
   @objc dynamic var idCar = "" 
   @objc dynamic var station: Station?  // Link to a Station Object
   @objc dynamic var car: Car?  // Link to a car Object
```

Car.swift

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

final class Car : Object {

//@objc dynamic var ID = 0
@objc dynamic var idCar = ""
//...some fields
@objc dynamic var data: NSData?

// Link to Conso object (Many-to-One)
let consos = LinkingObjects(fromType: Conso.self, property: "car")
```

Station.swift

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import MapKit

final class Station : Object {

//@objc dynamic var ID = 0
@objc dynamic var idStation = ""
//...some fields
@objc dynamic var data: NSData?
// Link to Conso object (Many-to-One)
let consos = LinkingObjects(fromType: Conso.self, property: "station")
```

I insert the objects on database using this snippet :

```
// Create a Conso Object
let conso:Conso = Conso()
conso.idConso = "Conso-123454344"

if let textStationService = self.TextFieldStationService.text{
            conso.nomStation = textStationService
            conso.station?.nomStation = textStationService
}

if let textCPStationService = self.TextFieldCodePostal.text{
            conso.CPStation = textCPStationService
            self.station!.codePostal = textCPStationService
        }

if let textVilleStationService = self.TextFieldStationServiceCPVille.text{
            conso.villeStation = textVilleStationService
            self.station!.ville = textVilleStationService
        }

// A car object is received from another viewController
conso.car = self.car 

let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
  realm.add(conso)
  realm.add(station!)
}
```

From another ViewController, I get the results with this snippet
assumed that a car id (idCar) is received from another VC :

```
func listConso(){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    // Get the car from its id
    self.car = realm.objects(Car.self).filter("idCar = %@",self.idCar).first
    // Get Conso based on the searched car
    self.consosData = realm.objects(Car.self).filter("idCar = %@",self.idCar).first?.consos.sorted(byKeyPath: "dateConso", ascending: false)
    self.consos = Array((self.consosData)!)


    self.tableViewConso.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    self.tableViewConso.reloadData()
    print("listConsop")
}
```

The result is that I have many lines twice

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I assume that the tableview datasource in the VC is using the contents of tableViewConso to control the number of rows etc, and there is no problem here. I'd verify this with the debugger by looking at tableViewConso (not the data itself as this will be inaccessible, but the row count). If this is incorrect to your expectations then I'd check that the 'add snippet' isn't being called twice (again, breakpoints to confirm). I would add code to print the number of rows in the query at each step of the adding routine. Are conso objects added from anywhere else? I can see no obvious problems.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. The error came from the count of number of rows.